# Passing multiple POST request parameters C++ libcurl

Tags: c++, api, curl, spotify, libcurl

Currently using the C++ implementation of libcurl to interact with the Spotify API, looking for a way to pass multiple 'Request Body Parameters' during a POST request. The fields required are:

[image: Fields needed]

Looking at the [example of a POST request](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html) found in libcurl's documentation, it seems that this line:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");
```

passes two parameters: "name" and "project". When I try a similar format with Spotify's API:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&code=abcdef&redirect_uri=example.com");
```

I get the following error:

```json
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}
```

I've validated that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` works for this case, by passing only the `"grant_type"`, because the API response tells me that my request is missing a code, so clearly the API is reading the `POSTFIELDS` argument.

Does anyone have any insight on how to include multiple parameters in a `POST` request?

EDIT: Providing a minimal reproducible example:
As part of the oAuth flow, this example happens AFTER the user receives a oAuth access token

```
CURL *curl;
std::string res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
    
if(curl) {
    try {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&code=abcdef&redirect_uri=example.com");     
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &res);

        std::string enc = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>((myClientID + ":" + myClientSecret).data()), (myclientID + ":" + myClientSecret).length(), false);
            
        std::string httpAuth = "Authorization: Basic " + enc;
        struct curl_slist *authChunk = nullptr;
        authChunk = curl_slist_append(authChunk, httpAuth.c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, authChunk);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    catch (const char* Exception) {
        std::cerr << Exception << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `curl_easy_setopt()` call looks fine to me, assuming you are using a proper `code` and `redirect_uri` in your real code. You are going to have to provide a [mcve]. The Spotify API provides `curl` examples, which are fairly easy to translate to libcurl.

Comment: Added the example. Yes, code and redirect_uri are valid arguments in my actual code. I originally used Python for this authorization flow, but decided to migrate to C++ in the context of a project I'm working on. I've been using the Spotify API curl examples, they've been a huge help in translating my code from Python requests calls to C++ libcurl. It does seem like that curl_easy_setopt() is correct and follows the curl example provided by Spotify, but I keep running into the error shown above.

Comment: According to [Spotify's Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/), you can't send a request to `/api/token` until you first send a request to `/authorize` to get the required authorization `code` that you can then give to `/api/token`. Your example is not doing that 1st step, unless you have obtained a `code` from an earlier run of you program and are trying to refresh its expiration date (but then the `grant_type` needs to be `"refresh_token"` instead).

Comment: Also, `this>WriteCallback` (should be `this->WriteCallback`) implies that `WriteCallback` is a non-`static` class method, is that right? You can't use a non-`static` class method with  `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. You would need to use a `static` method instead, using `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to pass in the `this` pointer.

Comment: On the this->WriteCallback: I have the correct syntax in my code, missed that when removing personal information for the code example. I'm interested how my other libcurl uses have been working in other use cases considering I have been using WriteCallback at a non-static method, but that's another quesiton. As for the logical flow of this code chunk, this example happens AFTER the 'user' receives a code

Comment: Did you verify that libcurl is sending a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, so Spotify knows how to parse the request body correctly? You can use [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to see what libcurl is actually sending.

Comment: Interesting.. no I have not validated that. Is that something I would have to pass as a header? Going to play around with ```CURLOPT_VERBOSE``` and see what I get

Comment: Use of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` *should* set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, but it doesn't hurt to make sure.

Comment: Ended up resolving this issue. The issue was with the redirect URI I was passing - I was initially passing it as a regular URL when I should have been encoding it. Passing redirect URI as an encoded URL fixed me issue. Thanks @RemyLebeau for helping me format my question and guiding me through debugging it!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this issue - make sure that you are encoding your `redirect_uri` parameter correctly when formatting your `POST` request. Here is what I did differently

```
// Wrote a custom URL encoding function

std::string urlEncEasy(std::string url) {
    std::string res;

    for (auto c : url) {
        if (c == ':') {
            res += "%3A";
        }
        else if (c == '/') {
            res += "%2F";
        }
        else {
            res += c;
        }
    } 
    return res;
}

// Changed my CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to
std::string postFields = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + myAuthToken + "&redirect_uri=" + urlEncEasy(myRedirectUri);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postFields.c_str());
```

Comment: Your url-encoding function is incomplete, there are many characters it doesn't encode. libcurl has a [`curl_easy_escape()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) function for url-encoding strings.